# How to add more information to Bitrise Checks

Tags: bitrise

We have Bitrise checks installed for our repo/app. Is it possible to add more rows for Bitrise checks?

Specifically, we want to display our code coverage % in this check.

Comment: You will have to write your custom step.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you mean by rows, but you can try using the Codecov Step in your Workflow on Bitrise. You can add the Codecov upload token as a secret variable, CODECOV_TOKEN, and set the Expose for Pull Requests option to true. This will allow you to view your coverage reports on Codecov and display your code coverage percentage in the check.

Comment: We don't want to use Codecov due to costs